# Why is it that wrapping as.Date() in sapply return a numerical data type, but whereas lapply returns a date data type?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, as.date

Where I work, the data set that we receive is formatted in character and so needs to be changed to their appropriate data types for any analysis in R.

But a weird thing I have noticed is converting the column containing dates from character to dates using as.Date within sapply converts the columns to number, whereas lapply converts them into the required date format.

I was just curios as to why such a behaviour takes place.

Comment: sapply does a lapply and the "simplifies" it. See the help file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, and excellent question.

It is due to the result type.  `sapply` returns a vector and the `as.vector()` step strips the class attribute.  This is unfortunate, but documented:

```
R> dates <- Sys.Date() + 0:2
R> dates
[1] "2020-04-25" "2020-04-26" "2020-04-27"
R> as.vector(dates)
[1] 18377 18378 18379
R>
```

(And the 'number' is how dates are represented internally: number of days since the epoch aka 1970-01-01. You get the same when you do `as.numeric()` or `as.integer(0` on them.)

Lists have richer semantics, and `lapply()`, which returns a list, does not incur the side effect seen above:

```
as.list(dates)
[[1]]
[1] "2020-04-25"

[[2]]
[1] "2020-04-26"

[[3]]
[1] "2020-04-27"

R>
```